# Change model class name in django admin site

Tags: django-admin

I would like to change a model class name in Django admin interface. I have used class meat is there anther way?
any help would be greatly appreciated

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meat:
       verbose_name = 'Comment'
       verbose_name_plural = 'User comment settings'
```

Answer (score 1):

You spelt it wrong. It is `Meta` and not Meat

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'Comment'
       verbose_name_plural = 'User comment settings'
```